# How can I obtain the folder path when right-clicking the background of a folder and invoking a context menu using a shell extension?

Tags: c++, dll, com, contextmenu, windows-shell

How to obtain path to folder  in which user made right click in its background to invoke context menu? For example, user opened "D:\projects" folder and made right click in empty background area of that folder and it sees a menu item in context menu named 'Display Path'. Upon clicking it, it should invoke a simple console app to display string "D:\projects".

It can be done by registry by adding "%V" as argument to command to console app, for example, "C:\myfolder\myapp.exe" "%V". Hence, this %V gives folder path to argument list of main() of myuapp.exe. Easy huh!

How it can be done using shell extension menu handler? I wrote a simple shell context menu dll which works fine and do its job, except that I don't known how to get that folder path as string where user made right click in background.

I found that path comes as PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl argument in IShellExtInit::Initialize() method. But, I couldn't get it in simple string format. The code is below which crashes, of course.

```
HRESULT __stdcall Initialize(PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidlFilder, IDataObject* pdtobj, HKEY hkeyProgID)
    {
        std::wstring s = L"null";
        
        // check msg, this msgbox is shown as expected
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Before", L"Initialize()", MB_OK);
                
                //have problem in this line, I guess
        SHGetPathFromIDList((LPCITEMIDLIST) pidlFilder, (PWSTR) &s);
        
        // check msg, sometimes this msgbox is also shown as expected
        MessageBox(NULL, L"After", L"Initialize()", MB_OK);
        
        // but this msgbox is never shown. I removed it but code still crashes
        MessageBox(NULL, std::wstring(s).c_str(), L"Initialize()", MB_OK);
        
        return S_OK;
    }
```

When I right click on folder background, it crashes and explorer restarts.

Does anyone know the problem and its solution? How to get folder path when right clicking background of folder to invoke context menu using shell extension?

In addition, how to get file/folder path when right clicking on it to invoke context menu using shell extension?

Thanks in advance

tried using this code too, still crashes

```
                IShellFolder *sf = NULL;
        STRRET pName = {};
        sf->GetDisplayNameOf(pidlFilder, SHGDN_FORPARSING, &pName);
        wchar_t *d = new wchar_t;
        lstrcpyW(d,L"nulld");
        size_t inst = MAX_PATH, outst ;
        mbstowcs_s(&outst, d, inst, pName.cStr, MAX_PATH);
        s = std::wstring(d);
                MessageBox(NULL, std::wstring(s).c_str(), L"Initialize()", MB_OK);
```

Comment: not sure about windows api part, but `std::wstring s = L"null"`; `(PWSTR) &s` would not work, is should be `s.data()` and you should reserve enough space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make `SHGetPathFromIDList()` write the string data to the memory address where a `std::wstring` object resides, which will not work.

Use a fixed `WCHAR[]` array instead, eg:

```
HRESULT __stdcall Initialize(PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidlFilder, IDataObject* pdtobj, HKEY hkeyProgID)
{
    WCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH] = {};

    SHGetPathFromIDList(pidlFilder, szPath);

    MessageBox(NULL, szPath, L"Initialize()", MB_OK);
        
    return S_OK;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to receive the string data into a `std::wstring` object, then you have to pre-allocate its internal character buffer and then receive into that buffer, eg:

```
HRESULT __stdcall Initialize(PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidlFilder, IDataObject* pdtobj, HKEY hkeyProgID)
{
    std::wstring s;
    s.resize(MAX_PATH);
        
    SHGetPathFromIDList(pidlFilder, s.data() /* or &s[0] before C++17 */ );
    s.erase(s.find(L'\0'));

    MessageBox(NULL, s.c_str(), L"Initialize()", MB_OK);
        
    return S_OK;
}
```

Otherwise, you can simply receive into a `WCHAR[]` and then assign that to your `std::wstring`, eg:

```
HRESULT __stdcall Initialize(PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidlFilder, IDataObject* pdtobj, HKEY hkeyProgID)
{
    WCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH] = {};
    SHGetPathFromIDList(pidlFilder, szPath);
        
    std::wstring s = szPath;
    MessageBox(NULL, s.c_str(), L"Initialize()", MB_OK);
        
    return S_OK;
}
```

---

Your 2nd example doesn't work for several reasons:

- Your `IShellFolder *sf` doesn't point anywhere meaningful. Use `SHGetDesktopFolder()` to get the top-level `IShellFolder` object which you can then use to parse `pidlFilder`.
- you are allocating only 1 `wchar_t` for `wchar_t *d` to point at, but then you are trying to copy more than 1 `wchar_t` into that memory.  You don't really need to allocate any memory at all, as the parsed `STRRET` already contains the necessary string data, so just use it as-is.  Otherwise, you can pass the `STRRET` to `StrRetToBuf()` or `StrRetToStr()` to get the data in a more usable format.
- you are not paying attention to the `STRRET::uType` field to know what kind of string data it is holding.  Don't access the `cStr` field unless the `uType` field is set to `STRRET_CSTR`.  `StrRetToBuf()`/`StrRetToStr()` will handle this for you.

Try this instead:

```
HRESULT __stdcall Initialize(PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidlFilder, IDataObject* pdtobj, HKEY hkeyProgID)
{
    IShellFolder *sf = NULL;
    if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetDesktopFolder(&sf))
    {
        STRRET pName = {};
        if (SUCCEEDED(sf->GetDisplayNameOf(pidlFilder, SHGDN_FORPARSING, &pName))
        {
            WCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH] = {};
            StrRetToBufW(&pName, pidlFilder, szPath, MAX_PATH);

            MessageBox(NULL, szPath, L"Initialize()", MB_OK);
        }

        sf->Release();
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I'm new to context so I guess I need to understand strings really very well. & yeah, second part of question (with IShellFolder) is not necessary, it was just a try from my side. I know it was total mess. Thank anyway for your explanation, I got all my answers and code works fine.